# Sympy can't find inverse laplace transform of a sum of easy terms

Tags: python, sympy

I'm computing the inverse Laplace transform of an expression which is the sum of relatively basics terms to invert:

```
>>> t = symbols('t', positive=True)
>>> s = symbols('s')
>>> inverse_laplace_transform(1 - 9/(s + 2) + 5/(s+1) - 1/(s+1)**2, s, t)
```

It seems to be able to compute each individual fine:

```
>>> inverse_laplace_transform(-1/(s+1)**2, s, t)
-t*exp(-t)
>>> inverse_laplace_transform(5/(s-1), s, t)
5*exp(t)
>>> inverse_laplace_transform(9/(s+2), s, t)
9*exp(-2*t)
>>> inverse_laplace_transform(1, s, t)
InverseLaplaceTransform(1, s, t, _None)
```

Yet when I take the sum of these, I get a long error saying it can't find the polynomial

> inverse_laplace_transform(1 - 9/(s + 2) + 5/(s+1) - 1/(s+1)**2, s, t)
>   sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialDivisionFailed: couldn't reduce degree in a polynomial division algorithm when dividing [EX(-1728*3**(1/3)*(9 + sqrt(93))**(1/3)*(27 + 3*sqrt(93))**(2/3) + 1728*3**(5/6)*I*(9 + sqrt(93))**(1/3)*(27 + 3*sqrt(93))**(2/3))] by [EX(1)].
>   This can happen when it's not possible to detect zero in the coefficient domain. The domain of computation is EX. 
>   You may want to use a different simplification algorithm. 
>   Note that in general it's not possible to guarantee to detect zero in this domain.

Does anyone know a reason why sympy shouldn't be able to do this on the sum of the parts when it can do it on each part separately?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bug in newer version. SymPy 1.0 used to work just fine:

```
>>> inverse_laplace_transform(1 - 9/(s + 2) + 5/(s+1) - 1/(s+1)**2, s, t)
-t*exp(-t) + InverseLaplaceTransform(1, s, t, _None) + 5*exp(-t) - 9*exp(-2*t)
```

Comment: I'm using version 1.1.1 and I get the same error as in the question. I use the definition of `s` and `t` as stated in the question and then I copy your expression from here, but no bueno.

Comment: @Reti43 maybe I'm outdated :P am on it, checking right now

Comment: @Reti43 well, looks like the newer version is buggy, since the older gave a correct result

Comment: Hmm that is odd that the older version worked, as I am also using version 1.1.1
I opened an issue in the repo, and got a response saying it may be unnecessarily combining the fractions rather than doing the easier way of using a looking table on the small terms. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13491